# ajax horizontal scrolling jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll

I am looking for a plugin that makes a `div` horizontally scrollable and as the user scrolls, content is loaded via `ajax`. The ajaxscroll Plugin [link](http://blog.yctin.com/archives/jquery-plugins-ajaxscroll/) does that, except - I need this to work in both directions. Meaning I need to be able to scroll to the left as well, having content loaded via `ajax`. 
My `offset` does not always start at zero.

If I have 200 Images to show with the `plugin`, I want to be able to center to Image # 100 and then enable scrolling in both directions.

Is that possible? Does anyone know such a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes, plugin i don'T know.

You could make an array of the files, and when someone ask for a pic, it bring back the array key, the key before, and the key after (if key > -1 && key < array.length, of course). Then load those pics with ajax.

You could make a secondary array to hold the key already loaded so if someone skip from 1 to 100 and then back to 1, it won't reload the pic many time.

OR you couls use the remove() and append() function to add a slide and remove the one you don't want anymore.

For the horizotal sliding, you can use jquery .animate() to move the slides inside a containing element with the css overflow:hidden;

Check out Nivo slider at http://nivo.dev7studios.com/, maybe he does the trick. i don't know, i don't like to play with other people'S toys. :P